# Closed form solution for a 3x3 matrix given some constraints

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to know if it's possible to find a closed form solution (even if not unique) for the $3\times3$ rank-deficient matrix M meeting the following constraints (in the equations below, $x,y$ are non parallel, nonzero $3$-vectors, $z=x \times y$ is the vector product of $x$ and $y$, hence perpendicular to both $x$ and $y$, $h$ and $k$ are nonzero constants, $M^t$ is the transpose of $M$):

$$M x = 0$$

$$M y = h z$$

$$M^t y = 0$$

$$M^t x = k z$$

The matrix has one eigenvalue equal to $0$; $x$ and $y$ belong respectively
to the right and left nullspaces of $M$.

What I'm looking for is an expression for the unknown $M$ involving $x \in R^3$, $y \in R^3$ ($y$ not proportional to $x$), $z=x \times y$, $h \in R$, $k \in R$,
all of which should be considered known.

Thanks very much for your time and help!

Comment: Have you worked out a (simple) example?

Comment: What is unknown $M$ or $x,y,z$?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your notes. I have worked a bit on the problem, and came up to the following presumed solution:

$$ M(\alpha) = \alpha \, zz^t + \left (\frac{h}{z^tz} \right )\, zz^t \, \hat{x} + \left (\frac{k}{z^tz} \right )\, \hat{y} zz^t \quad , $$ where $zz^t$ is a symmetric matrix, and $\hat{u}$ is a $3 \times 3$ skew-symmetric matrix such that $u \times v = \hat{u} v$ for two vectors $u,v \in R^3$. My solution depends on one parameter, $\alpha$. It all looks like the general solution to a linear system, where the second and third addenda form a particular solution, and the first addendum is the general solution of the associated homogeneous problem. But since the problem has a matrix $M$ as unknown and not a classical vector, I am not sure how the nullspace for this system looks like, and if there are other possible solutions... Thanks again for your attention!